# How to remove string from the json response

Tags: javascript, json

I'm receiving a response like this:

```
/*-secure-{"errors":["Runtime: Adapter 'DemoAdapter' does not exist"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/
```

But I only want the JSON data from the response. Like this:

```
{
 "errors":       ["Runtime: Adapter 'DemoAdapter' does not exist"],
 "isSuccessful": false,
 "warnings":     [],
 "info":         []
}
```

How do I remove the `/*-secure-` from the start and `*/` from the end of the response.

Comment: Json can't have comment, where did you get response like that?

Comment: I got the Response IBM Worklight server.

Comment: @xdazz: It's probably there to prevent people from stealing the JSON ;)

Comment: the same groups of people can or can't steal the JSON with or without the comments. So comments do nothing. Surely IBM would know this, awesome client-side devs that they are...

Comment: Yes. U r correct. but i want it to be json for my further process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
var str = '/*-secure-{"errors":["Runtime: Adapter "DemoAdapte" does not exist"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/';
var res = str.substring(10,str .length-2);
```

syntax is like this.

```
var str = data;
var res = str.substring(10,str .length-2);
```

where data is whatever string u get the response.

Answer (score 1):

Should be a simple replace:

```
var resp = <string>;
resp = resp.replace(/^\/\*\-secure\-\n/, '').replace(/\*\/$/, '');
```

Comment: in string how can i pass the whole string.    "/*-secure-{"errors":["Runtime: Adapter 'DemoAdapter' does not exist"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/". each json object has double codes(").

Comment: Try escaping it: "here is a \"quote\"."